# Support for IE7 browser using IceFaces

Tags: jsf, cross-browser, icefaces

HI,

We are using the JSF with IceFaces as the component libraries. As of now the application is only compatible with the IE6. It is not working with any other browsers. Our client requires to update the browser compatibility to IE7. We want to know is there any configuration change in the IceFaces to make it enable for the IE7 browser or needs lot of code changes.

Please give me your suggestions.

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<jsp:root version="1.2" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

    <f:view>
        <ice:outputDeclaration doctypeRoot="HTML"
            doctypePublic="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            doctypeSystem="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />
        <ice:outputStyle href="/xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css" />
        <ice:outputStyle href="/css/hp.css" />
        <ice:outputStyle href="/css/body.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hp.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/expandableSelectMenu.js">
        </script>
        </head>
        <body id="document:body">

        <ice:panelGroup id="headerImg">
            <div>   
                <jsp:directive.include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include/header.jspx" />
            </div>          
        </ice:panelGroup>

        <ice:panelGroup id="headerImg01">
            <div>
                <jsp:directive.include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/xxxx_Head.jspx" />
            </div>
        </ice:panelGroup>

        <div class="rootDiv">
        <div class="bodyContainer">

<ice:form id="XXXX">

        <ice:panelGrid border="0" columns="1" style="margin-top:-8px;">

            <!-- xxxx-->
            <ice:panelGrid border="0" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:-8px;margin-top:-8px;" styleClass="contentPanelHeader">
            <ice:panelGroup style="width:10px;" styleClass="tabNoPanel">    
                        <ice:outputText  value="1" styleClass="panelHeaderNo"/>         
                    </ice:panelGroup>
                    <ice:panelGroup style="width:836px;">   
                        <ice:outputText  value="#{mes.producto}" styleClass="label20px"/>           
                    </ice:panelGroup>
            </ice:panelGrid>
            <ice:panelGrid border="0" columns="1" style="margin-top:-8px;margin-bottom:-4px;width:862px;" styleClass="contentPanel">
            <ice:panelGroup  style="width:862px;">
            <ice:panelGrid columns="1" border="0">
```

This is the piece of code. I have the following doubts:

- We are using the `<div>` tags to place the components. Will it affect the browser compatibility.
- I have heard that there is ***Floating Div*** problem. What is that? Some one told that that is causing the problem.
- Please review the code and let me know what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Icefaces are you using?

We use 1.8.2, do all of our testing on IE7/8 and FF3+, and we've never had any major issues (although there are some CSS ones, occasionally).

Comment: We are using IceFaces 1.8.2. We found the display is not working in the browsers other than IE6

Comment: Can you post some sample code from your project? An entire jsp or jspx file

Comment: We are using the div tag in the jsp design. some sample:<div class="bodyContainer"><ice:form
   id="vt0002">
   <ice:panelGrid id="panelWindow" columns="1" style="margin-top:-10px;margin-left:55px;" >    
    <fieldset style="border: 1px solid; width: 500px; height: 50px;" >
      <ice:panelGrid columns="1" border="0">

Comment: It is still unclear what "compatibility" issues you are facing. Do you really need the <fieldset> tag? Whatever you put in the <fieldset> tag will be treated as one cell in your panelGrid

Comment: I think your issues are more about CSS

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the CSS issues.

Comment: I think Ali means its your custom CSS thats causing the problem. We've used IceFaces and RichFaces and it works without any issues in IE6+